# Can a spark job be paused and resumed?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

Is it feasible to pause a spark job (on spark with YARN as cluster manager) and then resume it from the point it was paused?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to pause/stop a running job in YARN. If you want to pause or restart from a particular point of execution then the ideal way would be to break the job into multiple smaller jobs and then use an orchestration manager like Airflow or Oozie to control this activity. In the case of Oozie you can do something like below

```
oozie job -oozie http://localhost:8080/oozie -suspend 14-20090525161321-oozie-joe
```

More details can be found here - https://oozie.apache.org/docs/3.1.3-incubating/DG_CommandLineTool.html#Suspending_a_Workflow_Coordinator_or_Bundle_Job